# Adding Scrolling to Fragments Screen in a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout and inside it I have a TabLayout.
And I display in the same activity a ViewPager with the fragments of TabLayout.
I can not make the scroll work when I slide over the fragment. Scrolling over the TabLayout and all CollapsingToolbar, is working.

When sliding through the fragment the screen does not roll. And when sliding TabLayout up scrolling works normally. How could I solve this?

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_perfil_empresa" />-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="180dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/hair"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            <!--<View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                 android:alpha="0.8"/>-->


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNomeCidade"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="São Paulo - SP"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_info24"
                    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Sobre"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />-->
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
                android:background="@color/cinzaMEdio"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarPerfilEmpresa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_outline24"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Mensagem"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_date_range24"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Agenda"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_collections24"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Fotos"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite_border"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="2.650"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:background="@color/cinzaMEdio"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs_perf_emp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>




        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_tabs_perf_emp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Screen :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@TiagoIB, it is late to answer but I put this code if anybody need it. This works for me.

Just put a ScrollView inside a FrameLayout.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

is not scrollable Toolbar

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Scrollable ViewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="****"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.285"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                 />

           ..... Another Views

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```